# Need choose 1 or 3 randomly

Tags: c#

How can I generate a random number that's either 1 or 3 (without including 2)?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
var random = new Random();
int GetRandomTile = random.Next(1, 3);
```

Comment: Just do random number between 1 and 2 and below that say if 1 then use 1, if 2 then use 3 instead.

Answer (score 11):

A work-around could be:

```
random.Next(0, 2) * 2 + 1
```

Comment: `random.Next(0, 2)` can only return `0` or `1`, so this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

do it like this:

```
var random = new Random(); 
int GetRandomTile = random.Next(1, 3);
if (GetRandomTile == 2)
   GetRandomTile = 3;
```

Comment: The second parameter of Random.Next(Int32, Int32) is an *exclusive* upper bound. This call will only ever return `1` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: my mistake, i edited it, but the logic is still the same. why negativate? :/

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it, since you're only choosing from 2 numbers, is to use a ternary expression that returns `1` if the next random number is even or `3` if it's odd:

```
int GetRandomTile = random.Next() % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 3;
```